# Cocos2d call display layer frmo another layer

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene called `AchievmentScene` to which I added a layer called `AchievmentsLayer`. This layer displays a list of achievements structured in a `CCMenu` with selector parameter a method called `itemPressed` which is the method called when the user presses a particular item.

Now this menu is dynamically created from an xml file which contains information like title, description, unlocked etc. When the `itemPressed` method is called after clicking on the item, I am able to pass the name and the description of the selected achievement.

Therefore please correct the following thought if it's wrong.
My goal is, when this method is called to display another layer on the scene with the appropriate z value on top of the list and in the center of the screen displaying the title and the description of the achievement and once a close button is pressed to remove this layer.

So is it correct when I say add another layer to the scene? And also the `itemPressed` method is inside another layer class, is it possible from a method within the `AchievmentsLayer` to add another layer ?

If I am completely off the track here, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a sample image of basically what I would like to happen after the user has selected an achievement from the list.

http://www.ezsite.gr/Layout_Design_Ideas.png

Any suggestions, tips or clarifications would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you want me to elaborate more in case my question isn't clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Small update. Iactually managed to solve my problem regarding how to add this layer but as it seems now i have a different problem. I added layer X on top of layer Y but layer Y is still active from below. Is there something i can do in order to disable/pause layer Y until layer X has been closed ? (If anyone wants to know how i did the above let me know)